# Is there a tool to allow the use of Android's 9-patches in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, nine-patch

I'd like a Javascript library that will stretch/scale [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#ninepatch) images correctly. Know of one?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on nine-patch images a while back and concluded they were an Android thing. Hence, I doubt such a tool exists.

If you are using this from a `WebView`-powered Android app, you could always use `addJavascriptInterface()` to expose the Java APIs to scale it for you.

Comment: I'm not using it from Android... I just think they're a great idea and would like to use them in web pages. Also, I'm too lazy to write it myself (something about hating Javascript).